# Laravel 5.2, error on empty array

Tags: php, laravel, exception

Simple situation. Multiple checkboxes:

```
<input name="check1[]" type="checkbox" class="magic-checkbox" value="value1_1"/>
<input name="check1[]" type="checkbox" class="magic-checkbox" value="value1_2"/>

<input name="check2[]" type="checkbox" class="magic-checkbox" value="value2_1"/>
<input name="check2[]" type="checkbox" class="magic-checkbox" value="value2_2"/>
```

It saves, and than i make a check if checkbox checked. Array in controller:

```
$checkboxes_array = array_merge($ch->check1, $ch->check2);
```

So, if "check2" checkboxes are not checked - i get an error:

> ErrorException in adFormController.php line 70:

How to fix it?

Comment: If a checkbox is not checked nothing about it is sent. And your question is missing a bunch of information. `ErrorException in adFormController.php line 70:` provides no useful information whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, if not checked - no stored. but i need to display not checked too. So, i should pass to view array of all sections...
Line 70:
`$checkboxes_array = array_merge($ch->check1, $ch->check2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically at some point you need to check if the request has the input with that name. In this case:

```
if(!isset(request('check1')){
  $ch->check1 = [0,0];
}
if(!isset(request('check2')){
  $ch->check2 = [0,0];
}
```

The way you checked them is prone to braking, because, in your case, `$ch->check2` is not set. Try dumping `dd($ch->check2)` before the `array_merge`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps! All i need is dummy array, if data not saved.

Comment: Exactly, glad I could be of help :] I recommend you do this sort of stuff inside a separate class. Laravel already has them (laravel is amazing). Research [FormRequestValidation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation)